# Php y Mysql como inserto el valor de un campo de una tabla en otro campo de otra tabla que están relacionadas dentro de la misma bbdd

Tags: php, mysql, sql

me gustaría saber como puedo insertar el campo de una tabla en otro campo de otra tabla. El campo lo paso mediante _GET *`$id = $_GET['id'];`* y después lo muestro en un input de un formulario *`value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">`*, hasta ahí no hay problema me lo muestra en el value. El problema lo tengo dentro de este formulario cuando recojo los valores y los almaceno en otra tabla donde también quiero almacenar el valor del campo pasado `$id = $_GET['id'];` lo hago mediante un Inner Join pero no tengo claro si sería así, ya que no lo almacena, cuando imprimo el valor del select me devuelve false : *`INSERT INTO acomoda(aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('1', '0.02', '0.09', '2020-08-08', '0.06', '0.07', '0.24', '0.54') INNER JOIN personas WHERE acomoda.id_cliente = personas.idbool(false)`*
las tablas las tengo creada así:
tabla acomoda donde almaceno los datos recogidos del formulario:

```
CREATE TABLE `acomoda` (
 `id_acomoda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `aaod` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `aaoi` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `flexiod` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `flexioi` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `memod` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `memoi` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `fecha` date NOT NULL,
 `arnap` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_acomoda`),
 KEY `acomoda_personas` (`id_cliente`),
 CONSTRAINT `acomoda_personas` FOREIGN KEY (`id_cliente`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

tabla personas de donde recojo el campo id para almacenarlo en la tabla acomoda en el campo id_cliente y así pueda relacionarlas para hacer luego consultas.

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `telefono` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `estado_civil` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `hijos` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `intereses` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `apellido1` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `apellido2` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `dni` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `fecha` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

1
Y esta es la página donde tengo el formulario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    //aqui tengo que ver coomo insertar en la tabla acomoda el id de la tabla personas para asignarle el mismo id al id_cliente de la tabla acomoda a la misma vez que almaceno todos los datos en acomoda.

    //$sql = "INSERT INTO acomoda (id) VALUES ('$id_cliente')";
    
?>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Insertar valores Acomoda</title>
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1>Inserta Valores en Acomoda</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="insertar_acomoda.php">
          <div class="form-group" class="col-sm-2">
            <label>Revisión: </label> 
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" placeholder="fecha" value="" required="required" ><br />
          </div>
          
            
            <label>Id Cliente</label>
            <input type = "text" size="5" class="field left" readonly="yes" name= "id_cliente" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><br />
            

            <label>aaod:</label>
            <input type = "number" name= "aaod" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required" ><br />
          
            <label>aaoi:</label>
            <input type="number" name="aaoi" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
           
          
              <label>arnap:</label>
              <input type="number" name="arnap" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
              
            
              <label>flexiod:</label>
              <input type="number" name="flexiod" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
           
            
              <label>flexioi:</label>
              <input type="number" name="flexioi" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
          
           
              <label>memod:</label>
              <input type="number" name="memod" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
          
        
              <label>memoi:</label>
              <input type="number" name="memoi" step = ".01" class="form-control" required="required"><br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">                
                <input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-warning" value="INSERTAR DATOS"><br />
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
<br /><br /><br />
    

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

            //$id_cliente = $_POST['id'];

            $aaod = $_POST['aaod'];
            //echo $_POST['aaod'];
            $aaoi = $_POST['aaoi'];
            //echo $_POST['aaoi'];
            $arnap = $_POST['arnap'];
            //echo $_POST['arnap'];
            $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
            //echo $_POST['fecha'];
            $flexiod = $_POST['flexiod'];
            //echo $_POST['flexiod'];
            $flexioi = $_POST['flexioi'];
            //echo $_POST['flexioi'];
            $memod = $_POST['memod'];
            //echo $_POST['memod'];
            $memoi = $_POST['memoi'];
            //echo $_POST['memoi'];


            //$insertar = "INSERT INTO acomoda(id_cliente, aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('$id', $aaod', '$aaoi', '$arnap', '$fecha', '$flexiod', '$flexioi', '$memod', '$memoi')";


            $insertar = "INSERT INTO acomoda(aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('$aaod', '$aaoi', '$arnap', '$fecha', '$flexiod', '$flexioi', '$memod', '$memoi') INNER JOIN personas WHERE acomoda.id_cliente = personas.id";

            echo $insertar;

            
            $resultado = $mysqli->query($insertar);


            var_dump($resultado);

    
            

        }

    ?>

    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me parece que hay un error de comprensión sobre **cómo** funcionan las cosas y por tanto la forma de resolver el problema está mal enfocada. Para ayudarte mejor, olvidando por el momento tu actual código, explícanos el contexto: cómo se relacionan las tablas y por qué. Parecería que hay que insertar un ID de la tabla personas en acomoda ¿? Explica cómo pones ese ID en contexto para ser insertado o como se decide que ese es el dato (fila) que corresponde.

Comment: @A.Cedano  Mi intención es hacer una aplicación que recoja los valores optometricos de los pacientes de una óptica. Sería almacenar los valores optometricos recogidos en la tabla acomoda y relacionar estos datos con cada paciente de la tabla personas. Osea el paciente X en la fecha 00-00-0000 ha almacenado tales valores optometricos, el mismo paciente puede tener diferentes valores según en que fecha se hicieran las mediciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano ...En resumen el paciente con su id correspondiente (id) de la tabla personas donde estarán sus datos personales al consultarlos mediante un botón accederá al formulario donde se recogen los resultados de los valores y estos se almacenan en la tabla acomoda los almacenará según el id del paciente (id_cliente). Así cada paciente tiene sus valores según la fecha en la que se hayan tomado, pudiendo consultar más adelante por id de paciente según fecha de la revisión.

Comment: @A.Cedano ...En un principio estoy intentando que me salga con una tabla pero mas adelante recogeré más valores donde se almacenarán en tablas diferentes habrá unas 18 o 19 tablas todas con el mismo tipo de datos en sus campos, numérico excepto el campo fecha revisión.

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor. Se agradece que esos detalles sean explicados **de entrada** en la pregunta, porque así uno tiene una idea del asunto al momento de revisar el código. De todos modos, hay cosas que no has explicado. Se supone que habrá un contexto en el que se registran los datos optométricos y en ese contexto está a mano el ID del paciente. Se escriben los nuevos datos y se mandan a insertar en la tabla de datos optométricos junto con el ID del paciente. Esa es la manera lógica de hacerlo. ¿Lo estás haciendo así?¿Lo estás haciendo de otro modo? ¿por qué?

Comment: El INSERT debería ser precisamente el que tienes comentado: `$insertar = "INSERT INTO acomoda(id_cliente, aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('$id', $aaod', '$aaoi', '$arnap', '$fecha', '$flexiod', '$flexioi', '$memod', '$memoi')";` pues según los `CREATE TABLE` la columna de relación entre `acomoda` y `persona` es `id_cliente`. ¿Por qué no estás usando ese INSERT?

Comment: el id del paciente se recoge mediante el método _GET aparece arriba del código `codigo`<?php 
 include("conexion.php");
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id = '$id'";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);?>`codigo`  y lo inserto en el value del input mediante `codigo`value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`codigo` al hacer el insert en id_cliente del valor que recojo mediante _GET $id = $_GET['id']; es donde me falla, me aparece bool(false)

Comment: Lee mi respuesta por favor, creo que sigues confundido sobre cómo funcionan las cosas. Lo que mencionas en tu anterior comentario es cuando la página se carga para introducir los datos, pero cuando el formulario se envía lo que ocurre es el `INSERT` y es ahí donde tienes el problema que he explicado en la respuesta. Léela y si no entiendes algo comenta en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En los `CREATE TABLE` se ve claro que las tablas `acomoda` y `persona` se relacionan mediante la columna `id_cliente`. Entonces, para identificar a qué persona corresponde cada fila en `acomoda` tienes que asegurar que se inserte el valor de este `input` en `acomoda`:

```
<input type = "text" size="5" class="field left" readonly="yes" name= "id_cliente" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><br />
```

Para ello tienes que recuperar el valor del input en el servidor mediante: `$_POST["id_cliente"]` e incluir en el `INSERT` un valor para la columna `id_cliente`.

Es precisamente lo que tienes comentado en el código actualmente:

```
        // $id_cliente = $_POST['id'];
```

Sólo que el dato no se encuentra en una clave `id`, sino `id_cliente`, porque los formularios asocian los value a la etiqueta `name` que tengan los input, por eso no lo está encontrando con `$_POST['id'];` porque **el `name` de ese input es `id_cliente`**.

También había contradicción en cuanto a las variables, al recoger el dato desde el POST llamabas a la variable `$id_cliente`, pero en el `INSERT` la llamabas `$id`. Es un signo de descuido y de poco rigor en el código. Te recomiendo que adoptes una *convención de nombre* para tu código, lo cual evitarás errores de este tipo, que parecen tontos pero que te pueden hacer perder varios días ante tal trivialidad.

El código debería quedar así:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

    $id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
    $aaod = $_POST['aaod'];
    //echo $_POST['aaod'];
    $aaoi = $_POST['aaoi'];
    //echo $_POST['aaoi'];
    $arnap = $_POST['arnap'];
    //echo $_POST['arnap'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    //echo $_POST['fecha'];
    $flexiod = $_POST['flexiod'];
    //echo $_POST['flexiod'];
    $flexioi = $_POST['flexioi'];
    //echo $_POST['flexioi'];
    $memod = $_POST['memod'];
    //echo $_POST['memod'];
    $memoi = $_POST['memoi'];
    //echo $_POST['memoi'];


    $insertar = "INSERT INTO acomoda(id_cliente, aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('$id_cliente', $aaod', '$aaoi', '$arnap', '$fecha', '$flexiod', '$flexioi', '$memod', '$memoi')";
    
    //Resto del código
```

Así debería funcionar, salvo errores en otros puntos del código.

### Recomendación sobre seguridad

Como recomendación final, señalo que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Deberías considerar seriamente usar **consultas preparadas**.

Comment: He probado los cambios que me indicas y me aparece :`INSERT INTO acomoda(id_cliente, aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('8', 0.02', '0.03', '0.11', '2020-08-20', '0.13', '0.09', '1.04', '0.07')bool(false)` no los guarda, me indica Notice: Undefined index: id in .Esta linea  se encuentra arriba en este trozo de código `<?php 
 include("conexion.php");
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id = '$id'";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Es que tienes todo mezclado en tu código @RaulLognext. En el mismo archivo que registras los datos haces el `INSERT`. Te aconsejo que separes las funciones: por un lado la página que recoge los datos y desde esa página mandar el INSERT por medio de Ajax, usando un archivo intermediario distinto para hacer el INSERT en el servidor. Es la mejor manera de hacer este tipo de operaciones, queda todo mejor organizado y además no necesitas recargar la página para hacer un INSERT.

Comment: efectivamente necesito más orden , lo haré pero antes quiero saber como hacer que $id_cliente tenga el mismo valor que $id para almacenarlo en la tabla, seguramente sea una tontería pero ahora mismo no sé como hacerlo. Gracias

Comment: @RaulLognext si el valor está en un `input` solamente tienes que recuperarlo con algo como `$_POST["loQueHayaEnElNameDeTuInput"]`, es parte de lo que intenté explicar en la respuesta.

Comment: Así lo tengo, como me indicaste, es más si hago un `echo $insertar;` me aparece como verás abajo, creo que lo que pasa es que tengo que tener algo en la base de datos que no me deja almacenarlo. `INSERT INTO acomoda(id_cliente, aaod, aaoi, arnap, fecha, flexiod, flexioi, memod, memoi) VALUES ('8', 1', '1.03', '0.05', '2020-08-12', '0.07', '0.02', '0.01', '0.22')bool(false)` observa que aparece bool(false) cuando le hago un var_dump

Comment: Sí, la consulta aunque no tenga errores de sintaxis podría fallar, un caso típico es el de clave duplicada. Para salir de dudas puedes verificar con un `if` el resultado de `query()` y en el `else` imprimir el mensaje de error para depurar cuál es el problema concreto por el que está devolviendo `false`.